# Python - Appending elements to nested list

Tags: python, list, loops, nested, append

i want to add elements to a empty list, my code looks like the following:

```
A = [1,2,3,4]
B = [["a 1","a 2","g 8"],["a 3"],[],["a 5"]]
C = ["a", "g"]

D = [[] for _ in range(len(C))]  
D = [D for _ in range(len(A))] 

for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(B[i])):
        for k in range(len(C)):
            if B[i][j].split(" ")[0] == C[0]:
                D[i][1].append(B[i][j].split(" ")[1])
```

Output is:

```
[[['1', '2', '3', '5'], ['1', '2', '3', '5']],
 [['1', '2', '3', '5'], ['1', '2', '3', '5']],
 [['1', '2', '3', '5'], ['1', '2', '3', '5']],
 [['1', '2', '3', '5'], ['1', '2', '3', '5']]]
```

Output I want:

```
[[['1','2'], ['8']],
 [['3'], []],
 [[], []],
 [['5'], []]]
```

Same happens when i try to append the list manually (`D[0][0].append(1))`...every sublist gets appended in the same way.

I have ccordinates in A, different objects at this coordinates in B (for example `a 1` and `g 23` which are all named with a letter and a number. C is a list that contains the letters. Lets say i have 2 different letters (`a and g`). what i want to get is a list of lists of lists that tells me for each letter, which numbers are at specific coordinates. 
What happens is, that the append-command adds the number at the right position, but for every i...so i get a list of identical lists.

Do you have any idea what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters:

```
D =     [D for _ in range(len(A))]
```

`D` is a list of four references to the same list. This probably isn't what you want and will cause much confusion.

Just do the initialization in one step:

```
D = [[ [] for _ in C] for _ in A]
```

The `range(len(...))` formulation is unnecessary since you're not using the values. Iterating over a list with four items will iterate four times, same as iterating over a range of the length of the list.

Answer (score 0):

`D = [D for _ in range(len(A))]` creates a list with a bunch of copies of the same list inside.  Anything you do to one of them will also be done to all the others, since they are the same list.

It looks like what you want is:

```
D = [ [[] for ix in range(len(C))] for jx in range(len(A)) ]
```

Just as you did in the inner comprehension, you need to regenerate a new list each time in the outer comprehension.

(You don't actually need the `range(len(...))` stuff, as kindall mentioned in his answer, but I'm leaving that in to avoid getting into other issues.)

Answer (score 0):

This is your original code with additions to make it work.  This solution leaves your structure intact incase you needed A,B,C, and D.

```
A = [1,2,3,4]
B = [["a 1","a 2","g 8"],["a 3"],[],["a 5"]]
C = ["a", "g"]

D = []

for i in range(len(A)):
    E = []
    for k in range(len(C)):
        F = []
        for j in range(len(B[i])):
            if B[i][j].split(" ")[0] == C[k]:
                F.append(B[i][j].split(" ")[1])

        E.append(F)
    D.append(E)

for x in D :
    print x
```

The output is

```
[['1', '2'], ['8']]
[['3'], []]
[[], []]
[['5'], []]
```